# Android center horizontal not working

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I got this code, a linearlayout inside relativelayout... however its not centering horizontally... any idea why?

i want the linearlayout to be horizontall centered. i am filling it with images via code.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@color/list_background_pressed" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >           
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="HI! Welcome to My Zain"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_profile_1_64x64" >
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="10" >
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="The new Recharge Mechanism"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What results do you get? Also, there's a missing > in your layout. Did you copy the complete layout?

Comment: The LinearLayout in the RelativeLayout is OPEN... (Missing a ">").

Answer (score 2):

In the LinearLayout, try setting the layout_width to "wrap_content".  Right now, you're stretching it to the full width of the window, so there's nothing to center.

android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Answer (score 1):

add  `android:gravity="center"`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="10" >
```

Comment: This post was automatically flagged as low quality due to its length. It looks fine to me, but in the future I recommend adding a quick sentence or two explaining what your suggested change does and why it works.